# Python Reading Incorrectly

Tags: python

this Python code is selecting the wrong information to be the answer and it's selecting the first letter of the correct answer instead of the number corresponding.

```
#Trivia Challenge Game
#Trivia game that reads a plain text file

import sys

title = "Title"

def open_file(file_name, mode):
    try:
        the_file = open(file_name,mode)
    except IOError as e:
        print("Unable to open the file",file_name,"ending program \n",e)
        input("\n\n press the enter key to exit")
        sys.exit()
    else:
        return the_file

def next_line(the_file):
    """returns the next line from the trivia file, formatted"""
    line = the_file.readline()
    line = line.replace("/","\n")
    return line

def next_block(the_file):
    """return the next block of data from the trivia file"""
    category = next_line(the_file)
    question = next_line(the_file)

    answers = []
    for i in range(4):
        answers.append(next_line(the_file))

    correct = next_line(the_file)
    if correct:
        correct = correct[0]

    explanation = next_line(the_file)

    return category, question, answers, correct, explanation

def welcome(title):
    """welcome the player and get his/her name"""
    print("welcome to the quiz")
    print("\t\t",title,"\t\t")

def main():
    trivia_file = open_file("data.txt","r")
    title = next_line(trivia_file)
    welcome(title)
    score = 0

    #get first block
    category,question,answers,correct,explanation = next_block(trivia_file)
    while category:
        #ask a question
        print(category)
        print(question)
        for i in range(4):
            print("\t",i+1,"-",answers[i])

        #get answer
        answer = input("whats your answer:")
        #check answer
        print(correct," ",answer)
        if answer == correct:
            print("Right!",end=" ")
            score += 1
        else:
            print("Wrong!",end =" ")
            print(explanation)
            print("score: ",score,"\n\n")

        #get next block
        category,question,answers,correct,explanation = next_block(trivia_file)


    trivia_file.close()

    print("That was the last question")
    print("Your final score is",score)

main()
input("press the enter key to exit")
```

If you could point out why it's not working correctly that would be awesome =)

Comment: What is the expected output? What are the contents of the data file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code:

```
correct = next_line(the_file)
if correct:
    correct = correct[0]
```

gets the next line of the file, replaces "/" with "\n", then gets the first character of the resulting string. Without knowing the format of correct answers in the data file, I can only guess what you want to get out of this, but if the number of the correct answer is in a separate line, you should do this:

```
correct.splitlines()
```

then select the appropriate index of the resulting list.

Also, here:

```
    if answer == correct:
        print("Right!",end=" ")
        score += 1
    else:
        print("Wrong!",end =" ")
        print(explanation)
        print("score: ",score,"\n\n")
```

I suppose you want to display the score also if the answer was correct, so de-indent the last line for that.